# setup multiple azure web app for the same url?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

Say we have one azure web app and pointing to url http://www.example.com

The web app is in UK.

Now we have lots of customers from Australia, can we create another web app and hosted in Australia and still responding to url http://www.example.com?

Then base on the location of the user (i.e. where the traffic is from), the dns entry will be resolved to point to either the web app hosted in uk or in Australia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a service called Traffic Manager it can do just that. It has an internal integration with WebApps (if you use Standard or higher tier for WebApps).

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview

Comment: Hi, I know traffic manager. But I thought traffic manager is like a load balancer and redirect traffic. Are you saying traffic manager can redirect traffic base on dns lookup?

Comment: this is exactly what it does, the only thing it does @daxu